# IONIC Framework and JayData

Tags: jaydata, ionic-framework

I am using JayData to storage data.

To use JayData i need jquery.

When I put jquery.js my ionic.bundle.js don't work.

I am using IONIC with phoneGap and AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JayData without jquery by processing the results using callback functions or using q.js for promises.

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
```